# Configure Cent OS 6.4 so that desktop persists after closing VNC session?

Tags: centos, xfce, vnc

I want to configure my newly bought VPS to be able to automatically boot into the Xfce window manager and let users connect to it via VNC and still keep the window manager running after the user closes the VNC session. How can I do this?